# Find angle in secant/chord diagram

Tags: circles

What's the easiest way to show x=35 in this diagram?

[image]

I eventually figured it out by drawing in two lines and chasing angles:

[image]

However, this is a 10th grade question, so I'm sure there's an easier answer.

I sense that I've effectively re-proven some basic theorem about secants/chords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [inscribed angle theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem)